# Scrolling the page to a certain point of screen if less then certain size with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am helping a friend create a page for his game demo, and trying to set the page up were it will scroll by the header should the page load in a window smaller then 765px in height.  This is the [current page](http://play.teamandrecca.com).

After doing a lot of Googling to find a solution, I had hoped throwing in some JavaScript to the tune of:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia('@media all and (max-height: 765px)');
                if (mq.matches) {
                    window.scrollBy(0, 0);
                } else {
                    window.scrollBy(200, 0);
                }
```

So far I am not having any luck getting it to work.  I really only have a very basic understanding of JavaScript, but as far as I know I can't use CSS/HTML to automatically scroll down the page when needed. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want `window.scrollBy(0, 200);`. Using `window.scrollBy(200, 0);` you are scrolling 200px to the right, not down

Comment: Indeed, it also seems the logic with `if` and `else` would need to be reversed when I look at the description. Actually... you don't even need the latter. `if (mq.matches) window.scrollBy(0, 200);`.